# Root to leaf path sum equal to a given number in python

Tags: python, tree

I wrote the following code for this problem in python which seems to work.

I understand that in python everything is bound to an object. So, in this case, wouldn't my `currSum` reflect the updated value as we go back up the recursion stack (I mean say we go to process the right child after we have finished recursing the left)?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def RootToLeafSum(node,currSum, targetSum):
    if node == None:
        return False
    currSum = currSum + node.data
    if node.left == None and node.right == None: #leafNode
        return currSum == targetSum

    LS = RootToLeafSum(node.left,currSum,targetSum)
    RS = RootToLeafSum(node.right,currSum,targetSum)
    return LS or RS


n1 = Node(1)
n2 = Node(2)
n3 = Node(3)
n4 = Node(4)
n5 = Node(5)

n1.left = n2
n1.right = n3
n2.left = n4
n2.right = n5

print RootToLeafSum(n1,0,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: The statement `currSum = currSum + node.data`, which is the only one that makes any kind of change to `currSum`, does *not* alter the object that that variable refers to; rather, it creates a *new* object and has `curium` point to it.  And as this variable is distinct from the argument passed from the caller (that is, a *different* variable referencing the *same* object), such changes have no effect on the argument.